# Current flow from the generating station to our appliances

Tags: current, transformer

So I read about how current flows from a generating station to our homes. And this is the order that I arrived at: Generating station--->step up transformer---->step down transformer---->distribution transformer--->meter in our homes.

Now my question is, as the appliances and switch, etc are all in the same path, does current continuously flow from the generating station till our meter, even though all switches are off in my home,  (which basically makes the path to my appliance  an open circuit as the switch is off)

Or does it flow from the station to some localised area in our house and then to my appliances when I turn on the switch? If yes, what localised area is this?

**Note**:  The water in the pipe analogy is really confusing. Water in a pipe flows from the tank till the tap irrespective of whether the tap is open or not. Does current flow from the station till the switch irrespective of whether the switch is open or not? It wouldn't, right?

Comment: Current doesn't flow until you activate the switch (simple version of events).

Comment: Ok, but when I do turn on the switch, where does current start flowing from? The generating station, because that would be the source?

Comment: There are electrons built-up at your switch and when you activate the switch, those electrons will push free electrons in your house wiring that pass through your appliance. Probably best to just imagine it as water in a pipe.

Comment: Yes but the water in the pipe analogy is really confusing. Water in a pipe flows from the tank till the tap irrespective of whether the tap is open or not. Does current flow from the station till the switch irrespective of whether the switch is open or not? It wouldn't, right?

Comment: Yes, electrons have built up in the wire just like water will have build up in a pipe when the tap is off. You should also review your questions that you have previously asked and, when you have a good answer, formally accept that answer.

Comment: I'm sorry but what did you mean by the last sentence?

Comment: Electronics from the generator circulate in that stepup loop. And the 100,000 volt loop retains its electronics. Then a 20,000 volt loop for your square mile of houses. Then a 2,000 volt loop for your street. Finally the pole-pig provides +-110 voltsAC, and those electrons enter your dishwasher.

Answer (score 0):

In the imperfect water analogy, the water is electrons (charge).

Current is flow of charge. The water at your local community water treatment plant will flow slightly more when you open your tap.

There are electrons in a wire and water in your pipes all the time, but the electrons don't start to flow until you close the switch, and the water does not begin to flow in your pipes until you open the tap. Your local water treatment facility will experience a slight increase in outflow when you open your tap.

In fact there are so many electrons in metals that they don't need to flow very fast at all to represent enormous currents. Sort of like an enormously large pipe (in comparison to your typical needs).

Comment: I'm sorry if this doubt seems stupid, but the current from the generating station continuously flows to our homes irrespective of whether the switches in my home are off right?

Comment: No, the voltage does. The analogy is that there is water **pressure** not flow.

Comment: That's fine. But I'm asking about the current flow in specific. Does current from the station flow only when we turn on the switch in our homes?

Comment: If yours was the only house, and that was the only circuit at your house, it would not flow at the station until you flipped the switch. (ignoring non ideal stuff)

Comment: Ok, but if now there are other houses who've turned on their switch, but my house hasn't. Now current would flow from the station to the other houses, but what about mine? Does current to my house flow directly from the station?

Comment: It is commingled with current flowing to the other houses. They all add up to the total current flowing from the station. Ideally and for resistive loads like light bulbs or heaters. There are complexities that shouldn't concern you at this stage but I might get lip^H^H^H suggested enhancements from others if I don't mention them.

Comment: I know it might be complex but I'm just trying to understand the basics of current flow, i.e. switch is closed, current flows and switch is open, current doesn't. It just gets very confusing! Also, what do you mean by the last sentence? 

Comment: The hydraulic analogy is just fine for multiple houses, imagine a tank feeding a long pipe with multiple taps. Turn all taps off, the pipe has water at a certain pressure (voltage), but the water is not flowing (no current). Turn one tap on. All taps still receive same pressure, flow goes from tank to single tap. Turn several taps on. All taps still receive the same pressure. Flow from tank increases because multiple taps are drawing water flow (current). At the tank, it's not possible to distinguish what flow goes to what tap, all flows are aggregated.

Comment: Ignore it, it's not for you.

Answer (score 0):

> The water in the pipe analogy is really confusing. Water in a pipe flows from the tank till the tap irrespective of whether the tap is open or not.

The water in a pipe analogy should always start with the pipe full of water. A better analogy would be a central heating system with boiler, radiator and pump. The system is primed (full of water) and as soon as the pump starts water starts flowing *everywhere* simultaneously.

In the electrical circuit the wires are full of mobile charges (usually electrons in metallic conductors but we don't need to worry about that). The generator or a battery are providing an electric field to try to push charge through the circuit. That's the voltage. When you close the switch the charge carriers can move and that is current. Note that the effect is similar to the closed loop water system or to a bicycle chain - current moves in all points of the circuit simultaneously.

> Does current flow from the station till the switch irrespective of whether the switch is open or not? It wouldn't, right?

Correct.

Comment: so where does **current start flowing from** when I turn on a switch for any appliance in my house?

Comment: It starts flowing everywhere at the same time. It is pushed by the generator. When you turn on the radiator tap in the central heating circuit the water doesn't come *from* anywhere - it's already there - it just starts moving, pushed by the pump. When I start pedalling my bike the chain doesn't come from anywhere - it just starts moving everywhere at once driven by the front chainwheel.

Comment: thank you. I'm very weak in my fundamentals and conceptual understanding of current and electricity so I apologise if my doubts seem too stupid. I really appreciate you for patiently answering every single one of them. Moreover, is there any way I could personally reach out to you(via email) for any other doubts I might have or would this forum do?

Comment: You must be joking!

Comment: what do you mean?! I was speaking with complete honesty.